# Can you style an iframe scrollbar without access to the iframe's css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, scrollbar

I am displaying the "like box" from Facebook (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) on a website.  All the scrollbars on the website have a custom look to them except for the Facebook "like box" iframe.

Is it possible for me to alter the look of the iframe's scrollbar without having access to the iframe's CSS file?

If not, has anyone found a work around to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it appears you can do it like styling any other element.
[Link](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/scrollbars.html) At the bottom it says:

> Setting an iframe or textarea scrollbar is the same as any other element. Either do it with classes, or add inline-style code into the tag itself.