# Facebook Like box with scroll-bar - Can it be styled?

Tags: css, facebook, styles, facebook-like, scrollbar

I have a facebook like-box on my site, and i want to style the scroll bar that appears in the iframe. But i cant seen to find a way to do it. Anyone knows how its possible, or if it even ARE possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That Facebook scrollbar is coded using javascript, maybe you could try and dissect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz go through this link http://rocketpopmedia.com/discover/2010/06/02/how-to-style-the-facebook-like-box-using-css/

I hope this is actually what you want

EDIT:

the question is already discussed in stckoverflow you can check this out [Can you style an iframe scrollbar without access to the iframe's css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813177/can-you-style-an-iframe-scrollbar-without-access-to-the-iframes-css)

Comment: read the question they wanted to style the scroll bar that appears in the iframe

Comment: just look at my link and then comment

Comment: i saw that, it is for styling the like box not a scroll bar.

Comment: ok i got it ... the question is already discussed in stckoverflow you can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813177/can-you-style-an-iframe-scrollbar-without-access-to-the-iframes-css

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this technique](http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) to style the scrollbar, however it only works in WebKit browsers (Chrome & Safari)

Comment: What about Firefox and IE ? Any technique there ?

Answer (score -2):

You can always simulate some scroll control with css.

Comment: -1: Although it literally answers the question, is this not a very useful answer. How can that exactly be done?

Comment: Do you have some basic knowledge of css techniques? I'm asking so I know how to formulate and answer/solution for you.